# Statistical probability of an incomplete transaction committed by Postgres

Tags: postgresql, transaction-log

**tldr**

After spending time with bad databases which I will not mention, I came to question even the point of a database.

I knew that they could serve a purpose to keep permanent data organized, but that was it.

After delving into Postgres with the great help of especially Craig Ringer & Erwin Brandstetter, I've now come to see what a database could and should be:

1. Convenient syntax
2. Customizable storage methods for performance relative to persistence
3. Organized writes and even reads through serialization
4. Confidence that writes should never be incomplete

...and so on.

**The point**

The crash course provided has made me just enough knowledgeable on 1) - 3) to be dangerous, but I know no details about 4).

It seems like well-written database software like Postgres are designed to ensure that a transaction will never commit incomplete data.

Speaking out of ignorance, nothing is perfect, so in that vein, how statistically likely is it that Postgres will incompletely commit a transaction and not be able to detect the malfunction?

Comment: I can't give you a percentage. But in almost 15 years of working with Postgres I have not seen such a strange thing happening. Not once, not even with early versions. Hard to imagine how that could happen with the MVCC model. Nothing is visible for concurrent transactions until your transaction has committed. And any exception rolls back your whole transaction. There certainly are corner cases, but I am yet to experience one.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you Erwin Brandstetter!  Considering your experience, it sounds like the multiple layers of checks makes this as probable as winning the lottery.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Speaking out of ignorance, nothing is perfect, so in that vein, how statistically likely is it that Postgres will incompletely commit a transaction and not be able to detect the malfunction?

Barring undetected PostgreSQL or operating system kernel / C library bugs, and in the presence of good quality hardware with ECC memory, nil.

PostgreSQL's [write-ahead logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/wal-intro.html), where it:

- Records changes only to to write-ahead log
- fsync()s the WAL to ensure it's on disk and persistent
- and only *then* write the changes to the main tables

is extremely robust.

You do need to ensure that your operating system and hardware honours fsync requests properly. The `pg_test_fsync` program is useful for this, though the results require interpretation. Also, beware of cheap SSDs without proper power-failure protection.

The main risks to data integrity are:

- The system administrator
- Lack of backups and replication
- Operating system and PostgreSQL bugs;
- Cheap poor quality memory;
- Cheap SSDs without power failure protection;
- Faulty/overheating hardware, though on modern x86 you'll usually get MCEs warning you about issues

Anyone who gives you "statistics" or numbers on things like the probability of a future bug causing issues is likely full of it.

There's been lots of work done on transient memory errors; the risk is real but the probability is low. I've never seen a bit-flip error in the wild, but I have colleagues who have. Google has lots of info.

The most important thing is proper backup and admin processes.

[I wrote a bit more about this topic a while ago](http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/10/avoiding-postgresql-database-corruption.html).

BTW, there are a few exceptions to the rule that effects aren't visible until they're committed:

- Locking (obviously)
- hash indexes (don't use them)
- `SEQUENCE`s (and the `SERIAL` columns that use them)
- ... more others I haven't thought of

Comment: Thank you Craig Ringer! Would you mind giving a slightly more detailed description of the process that keeps such an eventuality from occurring? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-intro.html

Comment: It might help to think of WAL as data-and-metadata journalling, by the way. It's the same principle.

Comment: Wish I could give you another uv!  Thank you for your practical experience!